# Peut-on utiliser subjonctif sans le mot 'que' ?

Tags: usage

Je viens de lire une phrase en MSN :
'La pauvre... Elle est la fille de son père, le plus grave 
**qui lui soit**  arrivé c'est d'être née'

Pourquoi est-ce qu'on a utilisé le subjonctif ici, même s'il n'y a pas de mot 'que'. Jusqu'à présent j'ai pensé que le subjonctif est toujours suivi par 'que' et pas par 'qui'.

Comment: Pour signaler : il existe des cas d'utilisation de subjonctif hors subordonnée. Dans une démonstration en mathématiques : "Soit x élément de l'ensemble des réels". Ou encore l'expression "Ainsi soit-il". Ce n'est pas le cas ici, mais il faut garder en tête la possibilité d'exceptions

Comment: @Charly On dira beaucoup plus volontiers. « Soit x *un* nombre réel » que « Soit x *un* élément de l'ensemble des réels » (et le *un* n'est pas facultatif)

Comment: De même, dans un registre soutenu : Vive la liberté!  Périsse le tyran!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sur MSN, le français qui y est écrit n'est pas toujours en accord avec les règles du français.

Ici, « qui » est en fait l'abréviation de « qu'il (= que + il) »

> La pauvre... Elle est la fille de son père, le plus grave qu'il lui soit arrivé c'est d'être née

Cependant, quand on parle vite, ce *il* se fond dans le *que* et le *lui* à cause des liaisons, ce qui fait que l'on entend « le plus grave qui lui soit ».

---

Il y a d'ailleurs au moment une blague qui joue sur cette nuance.

> Question: Il y a des nains autour d'une bougie. Qu'est-ce qui fond ?
>   Réponse: La bougie.

Cependant, les gens ont tendance à comprendre la question suivante (et non celle écrite plus haute) :

> Question: Il y a des nains autour d'une bougie. Qu'est-ce qu'ils font ?

et ne peuvent donc pas répondre, car ils ne savent pas.

Comment: +1 pour la bougie (du sapeur ?).

Comment: En effet. Mais une réponse qui soit un tatinet plus complète indiquerait que c'est tout de même possible d'avoir un subjonctif sans « que ».

Comment: D'ailleurs je me demande si on a pas là un cas similaire à « ce qui se passe » et « ce qu'il se passe », qui sont tous les deux acceptés . « Le plus grave qui puisse arriver » étant par exemple [amplement attesté](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22grave%20qui%20puisse%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

Answer (score 2):

Bien que l'exemple donné dans la question soit, dans ce cas particulier, une faute d'orthographe, comme bien expliqué dans l'autre réponse, il est quand même possible d'utiliser le subjonctif sans qu'il soit précédé par « que » — mais, notamment, par « qui ».

L'exemple, légèrement modifié, serait donc :

> La pauvre… Elle est la fille de sa mère : la plus moche qui soit.

On en trouve d'autres exemples dans la liste ici: [French Subjunctive](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/subjunctive/). Généralement, on utilise le subjonctif après « qui » si on fait référence à une personne qui ait une qualité exceptionnelle ou recherchée.

Comment: Tout à fait. Mais par contre ça n'a aucun rapport avec le doute. Il faut arrêter de croire que le subjonctif a un rapport quelconque avec le doute autre qu'accidentel. Dans ce cas c'est utilisé lorsque la subordonnée sert de caractérisation.